# Python:Adding enemies and weapons in game (Text-based adventure game)

Tags: python, text-based, adventure-games

I'm a beginner in coding and game-design also and try to make text-based adventure game, where player should move between rooms, fight with zombies and pick up weapons. Any help, namely tips and pieces of advise regarding the direction are really appreciated.

How can I add more zombies in the game except those which are in room?

For now code is organized as follows:

```
def position():
# player's position
    print("You are in  : " + rooms[currentRoom]["name"])
# inventory
    print("Inventory" + str(inventory))
# weapon
  if "weapon" in rooms[currentRoom]:
      print("Pick up " + rooms[currentRoom]["weapon"])

inventory=[]

#dataset 
rooms = {
    1 : {"name" : "entrance", 
         "info":"Start of the game", 
         'N': 2 , 
         'E': 3 ,  
         'S': 'no such directory' , 
         'W': 'no such direction' },
    2:  {"name" : 'kitchen',
         "info" :'Here is a zombie! Use frying pan to fight against him', 
         'N': 'no such directtory', 
         'E': 4 , 
         'S': 1 , 
         'W': 5 ,
         "weapon" : "frying pan"},
    3 : {"name":'livingroom', 
         "info":'Here is another zombie who likes to play golf. Give him 
         golf clubs and run',
         'N': 4 , 
         'E' :'no such directory', 
         'S': 'no such directory', 
         'W': 1,
         "weapon" : "golf clubs"}
    ...
        }
currentRoom = 1

displayIntro()


while True:

    position()

    moving = input (">>").lower().split()

    if moving[0] == "go":
        if moving[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
            currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][moving[1]]
        else:
            print("There is no such direction")

    if moving[0] == 'get':
        if "weapon" in rooms[currentRoom] and moving[1] in 
            rooms[currentRoom]["weapon"]:
            inventory += [moving[1]]
            print(moving[1] + "got!")
            del rooms[currentRoom]["weapon"]
        else:
            print("can't pick up " + moving[1] + "!")
```

By running the code, only first word of weapons is added to inventory. Can you please explain what is a reason?

Comment: Whats wrong with the implementation that you currently have? What is it not achieving that you would want it to? As it stands it seems like your movement seems to work for your simple case, no ?

Comment: Now (after fixing lower and upper cases of directions) player can move between rooms, thanks.                                                                                                                  However I'm not sure about part of adding weapons :  weapon which is picked up is added to inventory not fully, namely just first word is added ( for instance: instead of frying pan , only frying is added to inventory after picking it up)                        
Could you advise regarding this issue?

Comment: Thats because of how you deal with the splitting of words, you split at all spaces and only use the second word from the list of words when adding it to the inventory. You could always just add the rest of the input directly, but it might be better to validate the full name first if you plan on releasing the game so that players cant lock themselves by using weird lines like "get frying pan on floor" they would get Frying pan on floor instead of the right item

Comment: That being said though now that your questions asks broadly about tips on dealing with your game it is out of scope for the stack since it deals with Q&A rather than discussion / general tips. So maybe refine your question to reflect the specific question you have. Also, in the future refrain from changing a question outright and instead show your fix and start a new question to help future programmers looking to solve a similar problem :3

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Now I see where is a problem :) I've decided for now to add rest of input (wepoans) directly. I'm sorry for incorrect construction of question. Will not do it in future.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, please feel free to share your solution as an Answer. It's totally OK to answer your own questions here.